# how to Run my Apk file automatically when android phone get unlock

Tags: android

how to Run Android Apk file automatically when android phone get unlock.
Which BroadCast Reveiver call when user unlock phone 
I have already an apk when Android device get Unlock then my apk that's name abc.apk automatically run how it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACTION_USER_PRESENT is fired when user unlocks the phone.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT

Note that this is a protected broadcast and if the user is using a lock screen replacement such as WidgetLocker or NoLock the USER_PRESENT may not be sent or may be sent at the wrong time.

For detecting WidgetLocker's unlock see: http://teslacoilsw.com/widgetlocker/developers

To run apk automatically you can do the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToApk));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Above code will prompt user to install the apk.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a service and register for **ACTION_USER_PRESENT** receiver in that service and then you can start your application..